# Promise is resolved successfully before the funcion has finished using Angular and Ionic

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic4, es6-promise, angular-promise

I have created a service that has a method that retrieves a token from an API, which is calling a subscribe() internally. This method is called from a component and doesn't return an Observable, just a string containing the token.

Then, there is another method that should be called from the component after the token has been obtained, however, it is always being called before the other one. I have even tried with async/await in the component, but it didn't work.

```
// api.service.ts
logIn() {
  if(!this.token) {  
    this.http.post(this.apiURL + "/token/", {username: "test", password: "test"}, options).subscribe(response => {
    if(response.status == 200) {
        this.body = response.body;
        this.token = "Token " + this.body.token;
        window.sessionStorage.setItem("TOKEN_KEY", this.token);
        console.log(this.token);
    }
  }
  return this.token;
}
```

As you see the method just returns the token, so I am creating a Promise in the component and once it is resolved calling the getProduct() method but it is called before the token already exists.

```
// product.component.ts

async getLogin() {
  const resp = await this.apiService.logIn();
  console.log(resp);
}

getMenu() {
  this.apiService.getMenu().subscribe(resp => {
    console.log(resp);
});

constructor(private apiService: APIService) {
  this.getLogin().then(resp => {
    console.log('Called');
    // Call before the token has already been created!
    this.getMenu();
  });  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your function `logIn` set the value of `this.token` in an asynchronous call `this.http.post` thus when you `return this.token;` it is not assigned already. You are returning to early. If you want to go with the **Promise** approach, then `logIn` must return a **Promise**

```
async logIn() {
  if(!this.token) {  
    return this.http.post(this.apiURL + "/token/", {username: "test", password: "test"}, options)
      .toPromise()
      .then(response => {
        if(response.status == 200) {
            this.body = response.body;
            this.token = "Token " + this.body.token;
            window.sessionStorage.setItem("TOKEN_KEY", this.token);
            console.log(this.token);

            return this.token; // important to return the token here
        }
      }
  }
  return this.token;
}
```

Note that I've added the `async` keyword to the `logIn` function, changed the `subscribe` for `toPromise`, chained with `.then` and added `return this.token` inside it.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks! That worked!  Maybe using an Observable would be a better approach?

Comment: Yes, using an observable will do the trick and it has some advantages over promises. Take a look at @Tomasz Flis answer. And don't forget to upvote if the answers were helpful.

Answer (score 0):

In `logIn()` method, you should return `Observable`.

```
logIn(): Observable<string> {
  return this.http
    .post(this.apiURL + "/token/", {username: "test", password: "test"}, options)
    .pipe(
        filter(response => response.status == 200),
        map(response => response.body.token),
        tap(token => {
           window.sessionStorage.setItem("TOKEN_KEY", `Token ${token}`);
        })
    );
}
```

And then in constructor

```
constructor(private apiService: APIService) {
    this.getLogin().subscribe(token => {
        console.log('Called');
        // Call before the token has already been created!
        this.getMenu();
    });  
}
```